# BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::withoutMiddleware does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Does anyone have any idea about this exception?

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

//Blog routes
Route::get('blog', 'ApiControllers\ApiBlogController@index')->name('blog.index')->withoutMiddleware('auth:api');
//User routes
Route::get('user', 'ApiControllers\ApiUserController@index')->name('user.index');
Route::delete('user/{user}', 'ApiControllers\ApiUserController@destroy')->name('user.destroy');
Route::get('user/{user}', 'ApiControllers\ApiUserController@show')->name('user.show');
Route::put('user/{user}', 'ApiControllers\ApiUserController@update')->name('user.update');
});
```

## Exception

```
BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::withoutMiddleware does not exist. in file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WithoutMiddleware` is a trait used in [testing](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/WithoutMiddleware.php). Also there is a method named `withoutMiddleware` in this [trait](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php#L114) used for testing.

If you want to exclude a route from middleware you may remove blog-routes from route group of `auth:api` middleware such as

```
Route::get('blog', 'ApiControllers\ApiBlogController@index')->name('blog.index');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    // other routes
});
```